# How to get the newest record of a minute processing window

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink streaming job utilizing [windows](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#window-functions).

My aim is to group the records by their internal `id` received within a minute and stream down only the newest record per `id`.

I figured out 2 possible approaches:

1. Using `reduce()`

   ```
   stream.keyBy(Record::getId)
       .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60)))
       .reduce((rec1, rec2) -> rec2);
   ```

   This works fine but seems wasteful as it is called for **each** and **every** record.
2. Using `process()`

   ```
   stream.keyBy(Record::getId)
       .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60)))
       .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<Record, Object, Long, TimeWindow>() {
           @Override
           public void process(Long aLong, Context context, Iterable<Record> iterable, Collector<Object> collector) throws Exception {
               Record last = null;
               for (Record rec : iterable) {
                   if (last == null || last.getTimestamp() < rec.getTimestamp()) {
                       last = rec;
                   }
               }
               collector.collect(last);
           }
       });
   ```

This also works correctly. I had expected it to be faster but it is **not** (it is about the same as solution 1.).

Can you recommend a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution 1. seems to be the best approach here.

Regarding you comment:

> This works fine but seems wasteful as it is called for each and every record.

The problem is that you don't know which record will be the last. Hence, you always need to store the last seen record. Since the result of a `ReduceFunction` is stored in state (either for the next evaluation of the method or to return it as the result), that's exactly what's happening here.

Your solution 2. is in fact less efficient (from a storage/memory point of view). It remembers all records that arrived within a minute and iterates over all of the when the window is evaluated. In contrast, solution 1. only stores a single value (the result of the last function evaluation).

You could implement a solution with a regular `ProcessFunction` and a timer, however, I don't think that this would be significantly faster than a window + `ReduceFunction`. Moreover, it would require a lot more code.